# How to append a row in CSV file to list?

Tags: list, python-3.x, csv

I have a CSV file contains data reviews and I want to append it to list.
Here is a sample in my file.csv:

```
I love eating them and they are good for watching TV and looking at movies
This taffy is so good.  It is very soft and chewy
```

I want save in a list all the words of the second line and print them:
['This', 'taffy', 'is', 'so', 'good.', 'It', 'is', 'very', 'soft', 'and', 'chewy']

I tried this:

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
 data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
 texts = []
 next(data)  
 for row in data:
     texts.append(row[2])
 print(texts)
```

My problem is it doesn't print anythings. Can anyone help here?.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post a sample of your `file.csv`?

Comment: without the input example your question sounds vague

Comment: I add an example from my file above. It is very large file

Comment: @YousraGad if you allow it, I made a little edit in your question so maybe it look clear, I hope that is what you want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to import csv, if you want to save all the words in the second line, you have to enumerate the lines and take what you want, after that split them and save it in the list, like this:

```
import csv
texts = [] 
with open('csvfile.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    for i, line in enumerate(csvfile):
        if i == 1:
            for word in line.split():
                texts.append(word)
print(texts)



$['This', 'taffy', 'is', 'so', 'good.', 'It', 'is', 'very', 'soft', 'and', 'chewy']
```

Comment: I did import CSV ... this is not my problem. my problem is (texts) doesn't print anythings

Comment: @YousraGad it looks like your csv has text inside, try to do this I updated the answer

Comment: Unfortunately no. I think my problem in **(append(row[2])** to the **(texts)**. it looks like it overrides the data. because when I print **(texts )** inside the for loop it gives me the results. but outside the for loop nothing but empty space.

Comment: @YousraGad I created a file and run the code and prints the third latter of each word.... that's rare, what do you want to achieve? did you tried my code and didn't worked out?

Comment: yes, I tried it and didn't workout .. I want all data in the row[2] to be appended to list(texts).